# Swift StompClient Vs SockJS not consistent behavior during connection

Tags: swift, stomp

I am using StompClient (https://github.com/ShengHuaWu/StompClient) to connect my iOS (swift 3) app to a stomp socket that is hosted in a Spring container.

It seems when using sockjs from a web browser, and connect to ws:/server/topic_name, it automatically adds a server_id and a session_id to the url (ws://server/server_id/socket_id/topic_name).

When I use the Swift StompClient, it doesn't seem to add these additional items to the path.

anyone know how get around this?

Comment: have you used ShengHuas client successfully? I see the same problem on my end, but I was kinda thinking we need to manually call appendServerIdAndSessionId on our URL

Answer (score 2):

Sockjs is designed for use in browsers, since WebSocket is not supported in all browsers yet. The url you mentioned above is the part of the sockjs protocol.

iOS has the native support for WebSocket. So you don't need to rely on sockjs. There are Stomp libraries like this one you can use https://github.com/mobile-web-messaging/StompKit.

One thing to notice is that, if you are using Spring container, and provided that you have the configuration blow in your application context:

```
    <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/spring-websocket-portfolio/portfolio" allowed-origins="*">
        <websocket:sockjs/>
    </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
```

You should connect to ws://localhost/spring-websocket-portfolio/portfolio/websocket.